# iOS 7: Force white text for clock/battery

Tags: ios

I am trying to figure out how to force the color of the clock/battery/carrier to be white in iOS 7. I am also curious if the

[image: What I have now]

What I want to get:

[image: What I want to get]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured it out!
I just have to go into my Info.plst file and set **View controller-based status bar appearance** to **NO**, and then add this to my AppDeligate.m file:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```